# Practical to use PHP comments instead of HTML ones so that users cannot see them?

Tags: php, html, comments

I've just started really using comments in my website (mostly HTML and PHP) code, because of my sloppiness and common errors.

I was wondering if it is correct, common, accepted, and/or practical to use...

```
<?php // This is a PHP comment ?>
```

...rather than...

```
<!-- This is an HTML comment -->
```

because PHP code cannot be seen (but HTML ones can be)? Especially if the comment is regarding some little bug I can't fix, that I don't want any users to see, would using PHP as a more hidden comment be better?

Thanks.

Comment: ehhm, yes?! question answered?

Comment: Whatever floats your boat, dude.

Comment: I think comments are to make code more understandable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP Comments for comments that you don't want your users to see under any circumstances, and use HTML comments for comments that you are ok with your users seeing if they use page source. If the comment includes code, then it would be best to use an HTML comment... All your opinion in the long run